# Unaccessible directory created by mkdir in bash script

Tags: bash, mkdir

When I use a mkdir in a bash script, I can't access the created directory in terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash

date=`date --rfc-3339="date" --date='1 days ago'`
date=${date//"-"/""}
mkdir -p ⁠$date --verbose
touch $date/foe
```

When I use mkdir in a terminal, everything is fine.
Here is the error I get : `touch: impossible de faire un touch « 20150518/foe »: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type`
I tried with quotes and without.
What did I do wrong ?

Comment: what is the content of `$data`?

Comment: Hint: `echo "[$date]"` and `ls -lQ`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if, you want

```
+YYYYMMDD
  foe
```

```
date=`date --rfc-3339="date" --date='1 days ago'`
date=${date//"-"/""}
mkdir $date --verbose #remove -p option
touch $date/foe
```

or with `-p` option, no error if existing,

```
date=`date --rfc-3339="date" --date='1 days ago'`
date=${date//"-"/""}
mkdir -p "$date/" --verbose #with -p option, add / symbol (quotes aren't mandatory)
touch $date/foe
```

if, you want

```
+YYYY
  +MM
    +DD
      foe
```

```
date=`date --rfc-3339="date" --date='1 days ago'`
date=${date//"-"/"/"}
mkdir -p $date --verbose
touch $date/foe
```

Comment: It works ! I believe it's the quotes and the '\' which made it. Thanks a lot !